# how to find words that made up of letter exactly facing each other? (python)

Tags: python

I have tried so many ways to make the function but it always failed.

for examples:

> "he is the boy."
>
> "bully him"

The first thing that is asked on the question is to find words that has paired such "boy",  "b" would be paired with "y" and "o" is unpaired and if "bully", "b" pair with "y" and "u" with "l" but the first "l" is unpaired

Then, the first letter in the words and the last letter in the words must meet this requirement:

```
word1= ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m')
word2= ('z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n')
```

"a" must only pair with "z", "b" must only pair with "y", and so on

so the output from "he is the boy" is only "boy", as "h" not pair with "e" and "i" not pair with "s", "t" not pair with "e"

however, for "bully" although "b" and "y" is included  but "u" and "l" is not included, so there would not be an output for "bully him"

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> tr = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklm', 'zyxwvutsrqpon')
>>> def isPalindromyWord(word):
        t = word.translate(tr)
        return t == t[::-1]
>>> s = 'he is the boy'
>>> list(filter(isPalindromyWord, (word for word in s.split(' '))))
['boy']
```

Comment: Neat!! For python 2.x, you'd have to do an `import string` and then `string.maketrans()`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> text = "he is the boy."
>>> word1 = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m')
>>> word2 = ('z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n')
>>> d = dict(zip(word1 + word2, word2 + word1))
>>> words = (w.strip(punctuation) for w in text.split())
>>> [w for w in words if d[w[0]] == w[-1]]
['boy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try:

```
>>> word1= ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m')
>>> word2= ('z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n')
>>> [w for w in s.split() if w[0] in word1 and w[-1] in word2 and word1.index(w[0]) == word2.index(w[-1])]
['boy']
```

Comment: hi.. sorry i want to ask what about if "bully"? "u" and "l" is not included?

Comment: This works as well: the test is only on 1st letter `w[0]` and on last one `w[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Condensing your `word1` and `word2` into a string called `alphabets`

```
alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

The following function will do what you want (It is not very pretty)

```
def find_match(s): 
    split_s=s.lower().split(' ')
    matches = []
    for word in split_s: 
        found = 0
        sum = 0
        for i in xrange(0,len(word)//2):
            sum += 1
            if alphabets.index(word[i])+alphabets.index(word[len(word)-i-1]) == 25:
                found += 1
        if found == sum: 
            matches.append(word)
    return matches
```

Output

```
>>> find_match('bully him')
[]
>>> find_match('the boy wants ')
['boy']
>>> find_match('the boy wants aazz')
['boy', 'aazz']
>>> find_match('the boy wants abayz')
['boy', 'abayz']
>>> find_match('the boy wants abasz')
['boy']
```

Split your input string to extract words. Then for each word compare the first and the last letter (and so on) to their actual positions in the alphabets (The sum of their indices in `alphabet` should be `25`,i.e. max index in `alphabets`). If every letter of the word is matched, add the word to a list of matched words

Comment: @Wuchun For future questions, try and post _some_ implementation (even though it may be wrong) of what you are doing. This will get you more help